# IPTables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: iptables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IPTables: No chain/target/match by that name](https://serverfault.com/questions/262666/iptables-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name)

I am trying to execute the following command in iptables (it's the first command I have issued to IPTables since I setup my new VPS, but when I execute the command below:

```
iptables -A INPUT POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source XX.XX.XX.XX
```

I get:

> iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

From the output I am assuming I would have to create a chain / target beforehand, but how would I do this?

I don't see where I am going wrong

Comment: This will be more suitable in ServerFault, Unix&Linux, or SuperUser. Flagged for migration.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append to both `INPUT` *and* `POSTROUTING`; you will need to generate a rule per chain.